# Question about work and job

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

A Japanese student told me that when she chose "job" in the sentence below her teacher corrected her and said that "work" is the correct one.

**However difficult it may be, I decided to do the _____(work, job).**

But I don't really understand why either of them would be wrong. I can understand that depending on the context one of the two might be more appropriate but there is no way of checking that since, as far as I know, no other information is given.

What does everyone think about this?

Comment: There's no further context, you say? Either's OK, depending on the intended meaning, just as you say. (Missing words aside, it's not a great sentence anyway; the tenses don't match well.) Probably more [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com) material, though, this question.

Comment: There's no way to know without more context. A **job** is often an assigned role or a specific task. It's also a noun. On the other hand, **work** can be used more generically—and is a verb in addition to a noun. (Although not in your example sentence.)

Comment: Thank you both for your input! I'm glad that I wasn't missing something here. This seems to be a case of a Japanese English teacher not admitting that she is wrong in saying that only one answer is correct here or is ignorant about the sentence itself being kinda bad. She discouraged my Japanese student saying that what I taught her is wrong. Sure is not a good teacher!

Comment: You're right about that, Anna and worse, did the teacher not notice "However difficult it may be, I decided to do the (either)" will always be wrong?

Teacher needed something like "However difficult it *might have seemed*…”

Few native speakers would fail to understand *… it may be…* but "comprehensible anyway" isn't at all the same as "correct", is it?